# Convertir array clave valor en objeto php

Tags: php

tengo almacenado en un campo de la base de datos la siguiente información:

> ["ES=hola","PT=ola","EN=Hello"]

Me gustaría convertirlo en un objeto en php, para poder llamarlo de forma clave-valor, es decir, la idea sería `<?=$language->ES?>`

Comment: Hola, edita tu pregunta porque tal cual como tienes escrito el array no es una sintaxis valida.

Comment: @Ivandez Creo que es una cadena tal y como él la guarda en la base de datos. Al menos eso he entendido yo.

Comment: puedes indicar si esto es un string o es el ouput de tus datos??? `["ES=hola","PT=ola","EN=Hello"]` no me queda claro si el tipo de dato que recuperas es un string o un array...

Comment: antes de dar una respuesta seria conveniente que el OP aclare su duda y el tipo de dato que recupera de la base de datos... pareciera que esta recibiendo un array de los lenguajes guardado en la base de datos; ya que no creo que pueda guardar comillas dobles asi de siemple ...

Comment: cómo almacenás si el valor tiene signo de igual o comillas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero que debemos establecer es la diferencia entre un array y un objeto:

***Array:*** [Link](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php)

> Un array en PHP es en realidad un mapa ordenado. Un mapa es un tipo de
> datos que asocia valores con claves. Este tipo se optimiza para varios
> usos diferentes; se puede emplear como un array, lista (vector), tabla
> asociativa (tabla hash - una implementación de un mapa), diccionario,
> colección, pila, cola, y posiblemente más. Ya que los valores de un
> array pueden ser otros arrays, también son posibles árboles y arrays
> multidimensionales.

> Una explicación sobre tales estructuras de datos está fuera del
> alcance de este manual, aunque se proporciona al menos un ejemplo de
> cada uno de ellos. Para más información, consulte la extensa
> literatura que existe sobre este amplio tema.

***Objeto:*** [Link](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.object.php)

> PHP incluye un modelo de objetos completo. Algunas de sus
> características son: visibilidad, clases y métodos abstractos y
> finales, métodos mágicos adicionales, interfaces, clonación.

> PHP trata los objetos de la misma manera que las referencias o
> manejadores, lo que significa que cada variable contiene una
> referencia a un objeto en lugar de una copia de todo el objeto. Véanse
> los Objetos y referencias

*Objetos y referencias*

> Uno de los puntos clave de la POO de PHP 5, 7 y 8 que a menudo se
> menciona es que "por omisión los objetos se pasan por referencia".
> Esto no es completamente cierto. Esta sección rectifica esa creencia
> general. [Link](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.references.php)

> Una referencia en PHP es un alias, que permite a dos variables
> diferentes escribir sobre un mismo valor. Desde PHP 5, una variable de
> tipo objeto ya no contiene el objeto en sí como valor. Únicamente
> contiene un identificador del objeto que le permite localizar al
> objeto real. Cuando se pasa un objeto como parámetro, o se devuelve
> como retorno, o se asigna a otra variable, las distintas variables no
> son alias: guardan una copia del identificador, que apunta al mismo
> objeto.

---

***Facilidad de PHP con el manejo de objetos y clases:***

Si vemos los Ejemplos de Inicialización y Casteo, podemos resumir que un objeto no es mas que una variable de clase con propiedades.

---

***Inicialización y Casteo de Objetos:***

Existen multiples forma de castear una clase u objeto

```
$obj1 = new \stdClass; // Crear una instancia del objeto stdClass
$obj2 = new class{}; // instanciar clase anónima
$obj3 = (object)[]; // Cast una matriz vacía a un objeto
```

---

***Implementación de Casteo:***

técnicamente estos dos códigos son lo mismo:

**Ejemplo #1:**

```
$obj1 = new \stdClass;
$obj1->propiedad_1 = "Hello World";
echo $obj1->propiedad_1;
```

output:

> Hello World

**Ejemplo #2:**

```
$obj3 = (object) ["propiedad_1"=>"Hello World"];
echo $obj3->propiedad_1;
```

output:

> Hello World

---

***El uso de `json_encode` y `json_decode` para la Serialización de Objetos***

String JSON: [Link](https://www.php.net/manual/es/intro.json.php)

> Esta extensión implementa el formato de intercambio de datos »
> JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) La decodificación se realiza
> mediante el análisis sintáctico basado en la implementación de
> JSON_checker por Douglas Crockford.

> Es de común uso JSON para leer datos de un servidor web y mostrar los
> datos en una página web. pero tambien se puede implementar en PHP para
> la facil manipulación y serialización de datos.

Podemos argumentar que `json_encode` y `json_decode` pueden ser el camino corto para el casteo de objetos y arrays a partir de un string estandarizado en formato JSON

`json_encode` Devuelve un string con la representación JSON de value: [Link](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php)

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

output:

> {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}

`json_decode` Decodifica un string de JSON; Convierte un string codificado en JSON a una variable de PHP. **principalmente un objeto**, si le pasamos un `true` como segundo argumento; los objects JSON devueltos serán convertidos a array asociativos: [Link](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php)

```
<?php
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

?>
```

output:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}

array(5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}
```

---

***Solución a la duda Planteada para las diferentes Opciones o Escenarios***

**A. Si estas trabajando con un Array** la estructura adecuada seria esta:

```
$arr = [
    "ES"=>"hola",
    "PT"=>"ola",
    "EN"=>"Hello"
    ];
```

y el casteo y uso seria así de simple:

```
<?php
$arr = [
    "ES"=>"hola",
    "PT"=>"ola",
    "EN"=>"Hello"
    ];
    
$obj = (object) $arr;

echo $obj->ES;
```

output:

> hola

**B. Si estas trabajando con un JSON String** la estructura adecuada seria esta:

***sugiero que adecues tu desarrollo para que uses un método basado en este punto.***

```
$json= '{"ES":"hola","PT":"ola","EN":"Hello"}'; // no se parece a tu ejemplo!!!
```

Lo ideal seria castearlo con `json_decode`:

```
$jsonobj = json_decode($json);

echo $jsonobj->ES;
```

output:

> hola

**C. Si estas trabajando con un array**, que devuelve tu base de datos y que contiene string con estas estructura, la solución es un poco mas compleja ya que hay que sanitizar el mal formateo que trae:

```
$arrDB = ["ES=hola","PT=ola","EN=Hello"];
```

esto lo vamos a lograr mediante un `explode` y pasando los datos por un loop `foreach`:

[documentacion explode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) y [documentacion foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php)

Solución:

```
<?php
$arrDB = ["ES=hola","PT=ola","EN=Hello"];

$new_arr = []; // para sanitizar el mal formateo usamos un nuevo array

foreach($arrDB as $value){
    $sub=explode('=',$value); //partimos el string en Array 
    $new_arr[$sub[0]]=$sub[1]; //usamos el array
}

$obj=(object)$new_arr; //Casteo Simple

echo $obj->ES;
```

Output:

> hola

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer el trabajo iterando por cada elemento, dividiéndolo a partir del signo igual (`=`) y creando una propiedad por cada elemento encontrado:

```
<?php
/* Datos originales */
$datos = ["ES=hola","PT=ola","EN=Hello"];

/* Creamos una clase vacía */
$language = new stdClass();
/* Iteramos por cada elemento de la matriz */
foreach ($datos as $dato) {
   /* Dividimos en un máximo de dos elementos la cadena */
   $elementos = explode("=", $dato, 2);
   /* Si hay dos elementos (había un "=") creamos la propiedad */
   if (count($elementos) === 2) {
       /* Para crear una propiedad con el nombre almacenado en el nombre de una
           variable deben usarse corchetes de la siguiente forma: */
       $language->{$elementos[0]} = $elementos[1];
   }
}
/* Exportamos el resultado para comprobar su correcto funcionamiento */
var_export($language);
```

El resultado de la ejecución sería:

```
(object) array(
   'ES' => 'hola',
   'PT' => 'ola',
   'EN' => 'Hello',
)
```

Por lo que, efectivamente, se ha creado un objeto con las propiedades `ES`, `PT` y `EN` que pueden ser accedidas mediante `$language->ES`, `$language->PT` o `$language->EN`.

Puedes ver el código funcionando en línea en la siguiente URL:

- http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7f437bd72b9c1300ad58c4a3151736a826223ca2

En caso de que los datos de entrada sean una cadena de caracteres, habría que realizar precisamente la conversión a datos nativos de PHP con `json_decode()`:

```
<?php
/* Datos originales */
$datos = '["ES=hola","PT=ola","EN=Hello"]';
$datos = json_decode($datos);
/* ... */
```

Answer (score -1):

Básicamente, estás guardando un conjunto de datos en un campo de una tabla en la base de datos. Para poder hacer esto, formateas ese conjunto de datos para que el resultado sea un valor de tipo cadena, que puedas almacenar sin mayor problema en el campo.

Ahora lo que necesitas es, digamos, "darle la vuelta" al valor que recuperas de ese campo, para convertirlo en un objeto con el que te puedas manejar fácilmente desde PHP. Osea, tendrás que crear una función o un método que realice esa tarea de conversión.

Pero, ¿qué te parece si en vez de apoyarte en un formato propio y arbitrario, que te exige crear métodos tanto para preparar el dato para insertarlo, como para tratarlo al recuperarlo, te apoyas en un formato conocido, para el que ya existen métodos o funciones de conversión? Te ahorrarías un importante esfuerzo, y tu programa sería más estándar, más "compartible".

Una opción muy buena es guardar la información en formato JSON. En tu ejemplo, el dato podría quedar así:

```
{"ES":"hola","PT":"ola","EN":"Hello"}
```

Y, a la hora de recuperarlo, simplemente le aplicas json_decode:

Te pongo ejemplos de pasar a json y viceversa (para ejecutarlo todo seguido):

```
$arr = array('ES'=>'hola', 'PT'=>'ola', 'EN'=>'hello');
$str = json_encode($arr);
echo $str . '<br />';

$obj = json_decode($str);
echo var_export($obj, true) . '<br />';
echo 'ES = ' . $obj->ES . '<br />';

$str = json_encode($obj);
echo $str;
```

También hay quienes deciden guardar los datos serializados, usando serialize() para ello, y luego unserialize() para recuperarlos. Ya no estarías usando un formato arbitrario propio, sino uno conocido, pero estarías ligado al lenguaje, PHP. La solución con JSON se suele preferir a serializar.

Por otro lado, un formato propio frente a uno conocido podría interesar para, por ejemplo, facilitar búsquedas en los registros. Para esto, se suelen usar formatos muy simples, como puede ser valores separados por coma. La intención de poder filtrar fácilmente suele asomarse con claridad. Creo que éste no es el caso.

Comment: Sé que no es exactamente lo que el usuario ha preguntado, pero a veces debemos salirnos un poco de eso y darle una respuesta que suponga una mejora sobre cómo está haciendo las cosas o cómo lo tiene planteado. A quien le pique, que se rasque, yo me como todos los -1 que haga falta, pero es mejor apoyarse en JSON que tener que crear nuevos métodos para poder guardar la información en la base de datos y luego recuperarla.

Comment: Supongo que el -1 que te dieron fue por responder la respuesta antes de que el OP haya aclarado la pregunta ... hay un bot de Comunidad que a mi tambien me llena de -1 me tiene harto ...

Comment: yo personalmente tengo una política de no dar votos negativos sinceramente un voto negativo no dice nada ...